# Sorting Awk array by last name

Tags: arrays, sorting, awk

In my script, I start with a file of campaign contributors and anyone who donates a collective $500 is eligible for a contest. Anyone who meets that criteria I add to an array with an incrementing index to adjust the size as needed. Each index is formatted as outlined below, with the X's being a phone number. In the END portion of the script, I need to sort this array by last name($2) for printing. I've done some searching but come up empty handed. I'm not asking for someone to type the script for me, merely to point me in a better direction of search or offer advice. I need help sorting the array contestants as currently it will be filled properly with the string values the way I need them for the assignment.

Where v1,2, & 3 are the campaign contributions, I am using `-F'[ :]'` in my command to get both spaces and colons as field separators.

Input File lab4.data

```
Fname Lname:Phone__Number:v1:v2:v3   
Mike Harrington:(510) 548-1278:250:100:175 
Christian Dobbins:(408) 538-2358:155:90:201 
Susan Dalsass:(206) 654-6279:250:60:50 
Archie McNichol:(206) 548-1348:250:100:175 
Jody Savage:(206) 548-1278:15:188:150 
Guy Quigley:(916) 343-6410:250:100:175 
Dan Savage:(406) 298-7744:450:300:275 
Nancy McNeil:(206) 548-1278:250:80:75 
John Goldenrod:(916) 348-4278:250:100:175 
Chet Main:(510) 548-5258:50:95:135   
Tom Savage:(408) 926-3456:250:168:200  
Elizabeth Stachelin:(916) 440-1763:175:75:300
```

Array to hold anyone > $500, $8 is created and holds the value $5+$6+$7:
the array is initialized and filled in for loop given below

```
$8 = $5+$6+$7;

contestants[len++]
```

Loop to check add people to contestant array.
name and number are arrays that hold their respective values for later use.

```
for(i=0;i<=NR;i++)if(contrib[i]>500){contestants[len++]= name[i]"   "number[i] }
```

Formatting of indexes(desired array values for contestant[len++]):

```
[0]   Mike Harrington (510) 548-1278
[1]   Archie McNichol (206) 548-1348 
[2]   Guy Quigley (916) 343-6410
[3]   Dan Savage (406) 298-7744
[4]   John Goldenrod (916) 348-4278
[5]   Tom Savage (408) 926-3456
[6]   Elizabeth Stachelin (916) 440-1763
```

Loop to print/check that array has been correctly filled(it is)

```
for (i=0; i <len; i++) {print contestants[i]}
```

Output:

```
Mike Harrington (510) 548-1278
Archie McNichol (206) 548-1348
Guy Quigley (916) 343-6410
Dan Savage (406) 298-7744
John Goldenrod (916) 348-4278
Tom Savage (408) 926-3456
Elizabeth Stachelin (916) 440-1763
```

Desired Final Output: Ignore formatting as it correctly displays in my terminal I just hard a hard time getting it all nice in here.

```
               ***FIRST QUARTERLY REPORT***                          
            ***CAMPAIGN 2004 CONTRIBUTIONS***                       

   Name            Phone             Jan  |  Feb  |  Mar  |  Total Donated 
Mike Harrington     (510)548-1278   $ 250   $ 100   $ 175   $ 525
Christian Dobbins   (408)538-2358   $ 155   $ 90    $ 201   $ 446
Susan Dalsass       (206)654-6279   $ 250   $ 60    $ 50    $ 360
Archie McNichol     (206)548-1348   $ 250   $ 100   $ 175   $ 525
Jody Savage         (206)548-1278   $ 15    $ 188   $ 150   $ 353
Guy Quigley         (916)343-6410   $ 250   $ 100   $ 175   $ 525
Dan Savage          (406)298-7744   $ 450   $ 300   $ 275   $ 1025
Nancy McNeil        (206)548-1278   $ 250   $ 80    $ 75    $ 405
John Goldenrod      (916)348-4278   $ 250   $ 100   $ 175   $ 525
Chet Main           (510)548-5258   $ 50    $ 95    $ 135   $ 280
Tom Savage          (408)926-3456   $ 250   $ 168   $ 200   $ 618
Elizabeth Stachelin (916)440-1763   $ 175   $ 75    $ 300   $ 550
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
SUMMARY
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
The campaign received a total of $6137.00 for this quarter.
The average donation for the 12 contributors was $511.42.
The highest total contribution was $1025.00 made by Dan Savage.
                ***Thank you Dan Savage***                           
The following people donated over $500 to the campaign.
They are eligible for the quarterly drawing!!
Listed are their names(sorted by last names) and phone numbers.

John Goldenrod (916) 348-4278
Mike Harrington (510) 548-1278
Archie McNichol (206) 548-1348
Guy Quigley (916) 343-6410
Dan Savage (406) 298-7744
Tom Savage (408) 926-3456
Elizabeth Stachelin (916) 440-1763

Thank you all for your continued support!!
```

Comment: You might be interested in http://awk.info/?Sorting

Comment: Please read both Ed and Simon's answers. As simon's is the simpler method, but Ed's is more viable and uses more advanced techniques.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `gawk`, this is straightforward to do with the in-built sort functions, e.g.

```
BEGIN {
    data["Jane Doe (123) 456-7890"] = 600;
    data["Fred Adams (123) 456-7891"] = 800;
    data["John Smith (123) 456-7892"] = 900;
    exit;
    }

END {
    for (i in data) {
        split(i,x," ")
        data1[x[2] " " x[1] " " x[3] " " x[4]] = i;
        }
    asorti(data1,sdata1);
    for (i in sdata1) {
        print data1[sdata1[i]],"\t",data[data1[sdata1[i]]];
    }
}
```

... which produces:

```
Fred Adams (123) 456-7891        800
Jane Doe (123) 456-7890          600
John Smith (123) 456-7892        900
```

In plain `awk`, the same result can be achieved by writing the array indices to a file, sorting that file and then reading the file back using `getline`.

Comment: In that case I'm glad I've been helpful but not so helpful that it harms your learning experience. By the way, I find that being able to write a Short Self-Contained Correct Example or [SSCCE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions), such as you see in the answer, helps me a lot when I'm learning. Once I've written my question that way, I often find I can answer it myself.

Comment: @Ed Morton-I appreciate the help man, but Im still new to alot of this. While doing the labs I am learning lots on the side. For a lot of this all you were doing was telling me I was doing it wrong, Simon's method worked and when we work and get an answer Ill uncheck it as you asked. You could've simply said "x y & z is a better way to load an array as opposed to the way you are doing it. I can see\tell you are obviously, much better at this than I am, and I do not take the advice for granted. I am adjusting my question again to include everything I believe you could need.

Comment: @Simon-I looked at SSCCE, and will begin trying to use it in future questions

Answer (score 0):

The way to approach this is to produce the pre-SUMMARY output as you read the data so you don't need to store all of your data in an array, just the people who contributed more than $500 and just insert them into the array in the desired order using an insertion sort algorithm.

You would do it something like this:

```
awk -F':' '
NR==1 {
    print "header stuff"
    next
}
{
    tot = $3 + $4 + $5
    printf "%-20s%10s $%5s $%5s $%5s $%5s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, tot
}
tot > 500 {
    split($1,name,/ /)
    surname = name[2]
    numContribs++
    # insertion sort, check the algorithm:
    for (i=1; i<=numContribs; i++) {
        if (surname > surnames[i]) {
            for (j=numContribs; j>i; j--) {
                surnames[j+1] = surnames[j]
                contribs[j+1] = contribs[j]
            }
            surnames[i] = surname
            contribs[i] = $1 " " $2
            break
        }
    }
}
END {
    print "SUMMARY and text below it and then the list of $500+ contributors:"
    for (i=1; i<=numContribs; i++) {
        print contribs[i]
    }
}
' lab4.data
```

The above is not a fully functional program. It's just intended to show you the right approach per your request.

Comment: -So I implemented you way of initializing the array's values, although I have to do this in a script so I just worked the syntax and all is well. I'm still having trouble sorting it though, I will keep working and check back in. Thanks again Ed

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you say "although I have to do this in a script" since what I posted IS a script. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort or just google "Insertion Sort" for the algorithm to do that and see http://awk.info/?Sorting for the implementation of various other sorting algorithms in awk.

Comment: -I got an email back from my teacher who was surprised at the creativeness of the file usage idea. But he actually worked with me on how to simply just write the array the way I had, and sort from their no need for a i and j nested for loop to sort. And I'm probably wording it wrong but all commands need to be in a separate file the command looks like this awk -F'[ :]' a4b.script lab4.data, not awk -F'[ :]' 'cmds here' lab4.data as yours is typed, I believe its called a native awk script. [link](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-2)

Comment: @Redeye Insertion Sort is the simplest sorting algorithm so I can't imagine what your teacher came up with that is simpler. And you absolutely 100% do NOT need a separate file for this since if you wanted to use UNIX sort you could just do `print listOfNames | "sort"`. No, it's not called a "native awk script" if it's stored in a file, it's just executing the script from a file vs executing the script from the command line, see http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Invoking-Gawk. I am very curious to see what you ended up with - would you mind editing your question to include it?

Comment: actually using sort the Unix utility is what I've been saying since beginning before u had me delete comments. and I worked with my teacher this morning on it. he said even the first way I had done it is more than fine for this lab, not in future. your thinking way to advanced. and yes I'll post my lab. I got 20/20 so thanks everyone

Comment: Sounds good. Is this an awk class or a shell class or something else? Is the point of this exercise to learn awk programming or to learn shell programming or something else?

Comment: -It intro to shell scripting so we started with bash scripts, did some stuff with grep, sed, and just moved into awk. Tbh, this lab is actually like 3 weeks ahead of the stuff that's due.

Comment: Oh, I thought you were doing an awk exercise. If it's general shell then these are the 2 ways to do it: `awk 'BEGIN{print "BEFORE"; print "b\na\nc" | "sort"; close("sort"); print "AFTER"}'` or `awk 'BEGIN{print "1 BEFORE"; print "2 b\n2 a\n2 c"; print "3 AFTER"}' | sort | cut -d' ' -f2-`. Either one will output newline-separated `BEFORE
a
b
c
AFTER`

Comment: -I used very simplistic versions of essentially those commands while playing around. But I really did enjoy the more advanced topics you brought up and am using some of them in the lab. But im working on my C++ lab and will update when I go back to the shell lab. Thanks for all the support man, I really needed it